# Best Practice for mocking system date and Location in Objective C unit tests

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, unit-testing, mocking, tdd

I'm trying to write a class in Objective C using a TDD approach.
The class should basically implement this protocol.

```
@protocol SeasonService <NSObject>

-(t_Season)currentSeason;

@end
```

`t_Season` is just an enum for Winter, Spring, Summer and Autumn.

Assume I have a class that implements the above, pseudo code below

```
@implementation SeasonServiceImpl

    - (t_Season)currentSeason
    {
        // Get Date
        int month = [self currentMonth];

        // Get Latitude
        float latitude = [self currentLatitude];

        // work out the season based on month and latitude 
        // (i.e, Northern or Southern hemisphere)
        return season;
    }
}
```

I can test the above public method by using a category to expose the `currentMonth` and `currentLatitude` methods, and then use OCMock to partial mock. That at least lets me test my implementation of the code to work out season it is based on the date and location.

BUT

1) To me, it seems like a code smell to be using a category extension to effectively make two private methods into public ones.
2) It's not testing whether I am fetching the location properly.

So how would I code this so I can test that I am fetching the current location correctly?
I mean, is the best approach here to have a different designated init method which accepts an instance of a `CLLocationManager`. That could either be a mocked instance, or a real one for when the code is running in production?
Also, should the `currentSeason` method change to something like `currentSeasonForDate:NSDate`?

Comment: what unit-test framework are you using?

Comment: This code is currently OCMock with OCTest (or whatever the built in framework is in XCode 4.5.x is). I will intend to use the new updated test framework in Xcode 5 for an equivalent iOS7 project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional solution to this sort of problem is [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), which helps drive [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). The job of the `SeasonService` is to determine what season it is based on the latitude and month. Determining/storing the latitude and month should probably should be the responsibility of other classes.

Depending on your system's requirements, this could be achieved either through construction parameters or method parameters. Either way would allow you to mock out a specific month or latitude directly instead of resorting to category tricks.

Constructor injection:

```
- initWithLatitudeProvider:id<LatitudeProvider> latitudeProvider
          andMonthProvider:id<MonthProvider> monthProvider { 
    // set ivars or properties
}

- (t_Season)currentSeason
{
    // Get Date
    int month = [[self monthProvider] currentMonth];

    // Get Latitude
    float latitude = [[self latitudeProvider] currentLatitude];

    // work out the season based on month and latitude 
    // (i.e, Northern or Southern hemisphere)
    return season;
}
```

Or method parameter injection:

```
- (t_Season)currentSeasonAtLatitude:(float)latitude inMonth:(int)month
{
    // work out the season based on month and latitude 
    // (i.e, Northern or Southern hemisphere)
    return season;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Greg. That's pretty much how I did it in the end, using Constructor injection. What you have here as the 'LatitudeProvider' is pretty much my class which implements the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol.